# Pattern matching with HKT - avoid having to cast return type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, higher-kinded-types

In the following example, while the pattern match is technically correct, obviously the casting is bad. Can I reformulate that without having to use `asInstanceOf`? I.e. change the way the pattern match is written or adjust the interface of `Transform`.

```
trait Pat[A] {
  def transform(t: Transform): Pat[A] = ???
  def expandList: List[A]
}

trait Transform {
  def apply[X](in: Pat[X]): Pat[X]
}

case class FoldLeft[B, A](outer: Pat[Pat[B]], z: Pat[A], itIn: Pat[B], 
                          itCarry: Pat[A], inner: Pat[A]) extends Pat[A] {
  def expandList: List[A] = ???

  def test(): Unit = {
    val outerList: List[Pat[B]] = outer.expandList
    outerList.foldLeft(z) { (y: Pat[A], x: Pat[B]) =>
      val t = new Transform {
        def apply[X](in: Pat[X]): Pat[X] = in match {
          case `itIn`     => x.asInstanceOf[Pat[X]]  // ugly cast
          case `itCarry`  => y.asInstanceOf[Pat[X]]  // ugly cast
          case other      => other
        }
      }
      t[A](inner).transform(t)
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you are curious what the *meaning* of `FoldLeft` is, here is some sort of example:

```
Pat(Pat(1), Pat(2), Pat(3)).foldLeft(0) { (y, x) => y + x }
```

(you get the idea; `Pat` is like a `Stream` *descriptor*, and so I'm capturing the AST of this process, i.e. instead of executing the fold-left, I'm creating a `FoldLeft` that represents that process, whereby `Pat(1, 2, 3)` becomes `outer`, `0` becomes `z`, the closure is "evaluated" with dummy patterns `itIn` (`x`) and `itCarry` (`y`), producing the pattern version of the closure, `inner`:

```
FoldLeft(Pat(Pat(1), Pat(2), Pat(3)), Pat(0), It("a"), It("b"),
  BinaryOp(Plus, It("b"), It("a")))  // similar to this
```

Comment: `outerList: List[Pat[B]]`, `z: Pat[B]`, argument to `foldLeft` should be `(Pat[B], Pat[B]) => Pat[B]`. In general, if `z: Pat[Z]`, the function in `foldLeft` should be of type `(Pat[Z], Pat[B]) => Pat[Z]`. I kinda understand your problem, but your code doesn't seen to fit together?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin sorry, this was a copy-and-paste error. corrected now (it compiles)

Comment: Could you briefly describe what the "test" is *supposed* to do? I've usually managed to solve all the "how to pattern-match a higher kind without asInstanceOf"-questions by redefining `Pat` in such a way that the `Pat` does the case-dispatching itself, and can thereby keep track of all the types that occur in intermediate results in the match. But since I don't understand what "test" is supposed to do, I'm not sure how to refactor that. Are there any good equational constraints that the whole construction is supposed to fulfill? In particular: what's the meaning of 'itIn' and 'itCarry'?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it's just the shortened story. Actually this is part of `FoldLeft`'s `expand` which is an iterator-version of `expandList`. So `inner` is a pattern which contains refs to placeholders `itIn` and `itCarry`, and now I unfold `inner` by actually plugging the "real" patterns and inputs into `inner` and rewrite that pattern. For the question it shouldn't matter, hopefully. So if you look at the transform, `itIn` is actually the closure argument for the sequence iteration variable of a "regular" fold-left, while `itCarry` is the closure argument for the fold-left's recursion variable.

Comment: My best guess would be sth. like `trait Pat[A]{ def subst[X](name: String, x: Pat[X]): Pat[A] }`. One could make it compile and avoid all `asInstanceOf`. However... Do you want to treat `It("a")` and `It("b")` as some kind of variables, and your `test` is supposed to evaluate the `FoldLeft` symbolically by variable substitution? Are you aware that it might be surprisingly difficult to implement capture-avoiding variable substitution? (I mean "difficult" as in "you think that *this time* you got it right, and then it crashes one week later"-kind of difficult). Could it be an XY-problem?

Comment: I want to add that there are good ways to represent ASTs with variable binders, it's just the `It("a"), It("b"), BinaryOp(Plus, It("b"), It("a"))` part that looks like it could lead to trouble.

Comment: Wait... "the closure is evaluated with dummy patterns": is this reification of higher order abstract syntax encoding? If you can pull off this stunt, then you definitely won't have any problems with variable name clashes ;) In this case, forget my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to use `asInstanceOf` in code where all the types are right in front of you, then it usually means that some abstraction in your code guarantees something it cannot fulfill in its type signature. Several places in your code seem suspicious:

1. The `Pat[A]`-trait tries to keep track of the types, but in the next line the `inner` body of the `foldLeft` binary operation *says nothing about the types of the holes it contains*. Which one is it now, is it type safety, or is it an AST of `(Any, Any) => A` with holes of type `Any`?
2. `Transform` comes along with a method of the signature `apply[X](x: Pat[X]): Pat[X]`, which essentially says: "I am a *natural transformation*, I will treat all `X` equally!", but then the first time you instantiate it, you treat some `A` and `B` differently.

The `asInstanceOf` creeps into your code because it's an attempt to uphold the illusion that those two abstractions `Par` and `Transform` do what they pretend to be doing in their signature.

To get rid of `asInstanceOf`, you have to keep track of the types of the variables in non-closed terms. This can be achieved as follows:

1. Use `Par[A]` to represent *only closed* expressions of type `A`
2. Create a separate trait `Par2[V1, V2, A]` for expressions with
   free variables of types `V1` and `V2`
3. Instead of `Transform` that pretends to treat every `Par[X]` equally, create a `Graft2[V1, V2]` trait that explicitly says in its signature that it can only fill in holes of types `V1` and `V2`.
4. Let `Var2_1` and `Var2_2` (subclasses of `Par2`) do some dynamic dispatch on the methods of `Graft2`

Then you might get something like this (compiles, works, no `asInstanceOf`):

```
/** A pattern that represents closed expressions
  * that evaluate to something of type `X`.
  */
sealed trait Pat[X]
case class IntPat(i: Int) extends Pat[Int]

case class BinopPat[A, B, C](
  a: Pat[A], 
  b: Pat[B], 
  op: (A, B) => C
) extends Pat[C]

case class FoldLeft[A, B](
  bs: List[Pat[B]], 
  z: Pat[A], 
  op: PatFunc2[A, B, A]
) extends Pat[A] {
  /** Symbolically executes the `foldLeft`-operation */
  def eval: Pat[A] = bs.foldLeft(z)(op.graft)
}

/** Symbolic function with two arguments of 
  * type `V1` and `V2` that returns values 
  * of type `R`.
  */
case class PatFunc2[V1, V2, R](
  v1: Var2_1[V1, V2], 
  v2: Var2_2[V1, V2], 
  body: Pat2[V1, V2, R]
) {
  def graft(arg1: Pat[V1], arg2: Pat[V2]): Pat[R] = 
    body.graft(Graft(v1, arg1, v2, arg2))
}

/** A pattern that represents non-closed
  * expression with holes of two types `V1` and `V2`,
  * which, once some patterns are plugged into the
  * holes, evaluates to a value of type `A`.
  */
sealed trait Pat2[V1, V2, A] {
  def graft(g: Graft2[V1, V2]): Pat[A]
}

case class IntPat2[V1, V2](i: Int) extends Pat2[V1, V2, Int] {
  def graft(g: Graft2[V1, V2]): Pat[Int] = IntPat(i)
}

case class Var2_1[V1, V2](name: String) extends Pat2[V1, V2, V1] {
  def graft(g: Graft2[V1, V2]): Pat[V1] = g(this) // no cast!
}

case class Var2_2[V1, V2](name: String) extends Pat2[V1, V2, V2] {
  def graft(g: Graft2[V1, V2]): Pat[V2] = g(this) // no cast!
}

case class BinopPat2[V1, V2, A, B, C](
  a: Pat2[V1, V2, A], 
  b: Pat2[V1, V2, B], 
  op: (A, B) => C
) extends Pat2[V1, V2, C] {
  def graft(g: Graft2[V1, V2]): Pat[C] = BinopPat(a graft g, b graft g, op)
}

/** Grafting operation that can fill holes of two types
  * `V1` and `V2` in expressions with free variables of
  * those two types.
  */
trait Graft2[V1, V2] {
  def apply(v1: Var2_1[V1, V2]): Pat[V1]
  def apply(v2: Var2_2[V1, V2]): Pat[V2]
}

object Graft {
  /** Helper method to simplify the construction 
    * of a `Graft2` when there are exactly two
    * variables.
    */
  def apply[V1, V2](
    v1: Var2_1[V1, V2], arg1: Pat[V1], 
    v2: Var2_2[V1, V2], arg2: Pat[V2]
  ): Graft2[V1, V2] = new Graft2[V1, V2] {
    def apply(w1: Var2_1[V1, V2]): Pat[V1] = {
      if (v1 == w1) arg1
      else throw new NoSuchElementException("No binding for variable " + w1)
    }
    def apply(w2: Var2_2[V1, V2]): Pat[V2] = {
      if (v2 == w2) arg2
      else throw new NoSuchElementException("No binding for variable " + w2)
    }
  }
}

val test = FoldLeft(
  List(IntPat(1), IntPat(2), IntPat(3)), 
  IntPat(42), 
  {
    val a = Var2_1[Int, Int]("a")
    val b = Var2_2[Int, Int]("b")
    PatFunc2(a, b, BinopPat2(a, b, (_: Int) + (_: Int)))
  }
)

println(test.eval)
```

This prints the following symbolically evaluated AST (I fixed indentation and replaced ugly anonymous lambda name of `_ + _` by `+Lambda`):

```
BinopPat(
  BinopPat(
    BinopPat(
      IntPat(42), IntPat(1), +Lambda
    ),
    IntPat(2), +Lambda
  ),
  IntPat(3), +Lambda
)
```

I hope that this is roughly what you wanted to achieve in your code. At least that's what I understood from your edits and comments.

---

Notice that I used "graft" instead of "substitute" everywhere in the code snippet. *Grafting* is a simpler term-rewriting operation, because it ignores the issues with variable name capture. It could start to behave weirdly if you begin to use functions inside functions, because the variable names could clash.

Furthermore, if you take this approach, you will need something like `Graft1`, `Graft2`, ..., `Graft22`, because you are essentially creating a symbolic replacement for `Function1`, ..., `Function22` in the standard library. However, note that my implementation of `Graft2` can *also* dispatch based on variable names, so `2` is *the number of types* of variables, not the *number of distinct variables* (the number of distinct variables can be greater than `2`).

If all this is too awkward, what you could do instead: drop the variable names alltogether and use ordinary Scala closures.

Comment: By the way, on the second thought: it's probably possible to abstract over the number of variables in a `PatN`-like expression, so that one can keep track of variable types, but avoid the duplication in `PatN`-case classes and term-rewriting.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough analysis. Indeed the argument types to a `Pat` are lost in the API. I understand the idea of introducing `PatFunc2` (or `Pat2`), however the ability to write `val test` as a familiar looking `foldLeft` call instead of essentially writing out the AST is lost, if I'm not missing something. That the shape of `BinOp` would be the same as `Pat2` is just coincidence in this simple example, but in general the `inner` pattern of course could be combination of multiple patterns of various shapes. Example: `.foldLeft(0) { (_, x) => x }` (doesn't make much sense but is valid)

Comment: The question was not about the HOAS-reification, it was about why you are losing type parameters of higher kinds and need to cast them by `asInstanceOf`. The possibility to write `foldLeft(0) { (_, x) => x }` instead of writing out the AST manually is a completely separate issue, it's orthogonal to the problem in your question. It is not "lost", I just didn't bother to implement it, because I wasn't sure whether you want to use the proposed `PatN`-things at all.

Comment: Right; again thanks for the explanation, and the concept of 'graft' which I didn't know about.

Comment: What I didn't quite get was: why are you trying to do term-rewriting at all, why not just keep the Scala closure and let Scala do the substitutions?

Comment: That's because the AST is serialized, and I don't want to have any closures at that point, because they make serialization way more complicated. For example, my serialization scheme is much faster and immune to Scala major version change compared to serializing the functions using e.g. `Serializable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165380/discussion-between-andrey-tyukin-and-0).